# Permutations of Boolean values in ruby hash

Tags: ruby

I need to implement a function which gets a array with Symbols as parameters like `[:a :b :c]`, and then returns a array which contains all possible permutations of boolean values mapped to those symbols in a hash

like

```
[{a: true, b: true, c: true},
{a: false, b: true, c: true},
{a: true, b: false, c: true},
{a: true, b: true, c: false},
{a: true, b: false, c: false},
{a: false, b: false, c: true},
{a: false, b: true, c: false},
{a: false, b: false, c: false}]
```

what is a elegant way to implement such a thing in ruby?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use [`repeated_permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) for this task:

```
[true, false].repeated_permutation(3)
             .map { |a, b, c| { a: a, b: b, c: c } }
#=> [{:a=>true, :b=>true, :c=>true},
#    {:a=>true, :b=>true, :c=>false},
#    {:a=>true, :b=>false, :c=>true},
#    {:a=>true, :b=>false, :c=>false},
#    {:a=>false, :b=>true, :c=>true},
#    {:a=>false, :b=>true, :c=>false},
#    {:a=>false, :b=>false, :c=>true},
#    {:a=>false, :b=>false, :c=>false}]
```

or with an array of keys:

```
keys = %i(a b c)
[true, false].repeated_permutation(keys.size)
             .map { |values| keys.zip(values).to_h }
```

Answer (score 4):

We can take advantage of fact that pattern of `true`/`false` in output hash follows binary number sequence between 0 to (2<sup>ary.size</sup>-1), and do something like below

```
require "pp"

ary = [:a,:b,:c]

result = (0...2**ary.size).map do |num|
  bool_array = (0...ary.size).map do |bit_pos| 
    num[bit_pos].zero?
  end
  ary.zip(bool_array).to_h 
end

pp result
#=> [{:a=>false, :b=>false, :c=>false},
#    {:a=>true, :b=>false, :c=>true},
#    {:a=>false, :b=>true, :c=>true},
#    {:a=>true, :b=>true, :c=>true},
#    {:a=>false, :b=>false, :c=>false},
#    {:a=>true, :b=>false, :c=>true},
#    {:a=>false, :b=>true, :c=>true},
#    {:a=>true, :b=>true, :c=>true}]
```

Comment: BTW: `Integer` objects respond to `[]` with the value of the bit at that index in binary two's complement representation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks a lot for that input.  Did an update to use `[]`.

Comment: You can avoid the `[true, false]` array by using `num[bit_pos].zero?`

Comment: @Stefan Thanks a lot, updated the answer with more readable version - the concise version was getting more and more unreadable

Comment: `repeated_permutation` exists since Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @steenslag My mistake. Sorry, not sure what I was doing - I think I saw some error and thought something else.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use recursion:

```
def permute(arr)
  first, *rest = arr
  return [{ first=>:true }, { first=>:false }] if rest.empty? 
  permute(rest).flat_map { |h| [{ first=>:true }.merge(h), { first=>:false }.merge(h)] } 
end

permute([:a, :b, :c])
  #=> [{:a=>:true,   :b=>:true,   :c=>:true }, {:a=>:false, :b=>:true,  :c=>:true },
  #    {:a=>:true,   :b=>:false,  :c=>:true }, {:a=>:false, :b=>:false, :c=>:true },
  #    {:a=>:true,   :b=>:true,   :c=>:false}, {:a=>:false, :b=>:true,  :c=>:false},
  #    {:a=>:true,   :b=>:false,  :c=>:false}, {:a=>:false, :b=>:false, :c=>:false}]
```